# How to position spheres that are created with the CC Ball action?

Tags: after-effects

I'm using the CC Ball action to make some spheres to illustrate a chemical reaction.

When I make the balls, the circle to move it is thrown to the left, and the actual sphere is to the right. I tried changing the anchor point, however I can't move the shapes wherever I want.

How do I change the position of the created shapes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using CC Sphere on a large texture instead.  It will wrap the texture into a sphere, which you can then move around in two dimensions.  If you need to pass the spheres behind or in front of each other, you could place the layers in 3D space, even though the spheres will still really be flat layers.

The other option would be to use some particle generators.  Make a single particle that doesn't move in each particle generator you need, then manipulate them within the generator.

Finally if you really need true 3D, use something like Cinena4D, then import the rendered animation into After Effects.

Answer (score 2):

CC Ball is a video effect to make an array of balls that video can be displayed on.  It isn't designed for making circles that you can move around like this.  What you want is a 3D shape object.  Unfortunately, unless you have a 3rd party tool like Blender to make a geometry you can import, there isn't an easy way to make a true sphere in AE.

The only real option I know of without using a third party tool is to take a period or circle shape layer, extrude it by its diameter and apply a curved bezel and adjust the strength until it results in a fully round sphere.